# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method error raised while running code available in github

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am trying to run the code available in github repo:
https://github.com/xahidbuffon/FUnIE-GAN/blob/master/Evaluation/measure_uiqm.py

measure_uiqm:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from glob import glob
from os.path import join
from ntpath import basename
## local libs
from uqim_utils import getUIQM


def measure_UIQMs(dir_name, im_res=(256, 256)):
    paths = sorted(glob(join(dir_name, "*.*")))
    uqims = []
    for img_path in paths:
        im = Image.open(img_path).resize(im_res)
        uiqm = getUIQM(np.array(im))
        uqims.append(uiqm)
    return np.array(uqims)

"""
Get datasets from
 - http://irvlab.cs.umn.edu/resources/euvp-dataset
 - http://irvlab.cs.umn.edu/resources/ufo-120-dataset
"""
#inp_dir = "/home/xahid/datasets/released/EUVP/test_samples/Inp/"
inp_dir = "/home/xahid/datasets/released/UFO-120/TEST/lrd/"
## UIQMs of the distorted input images 
inp_uqims = measure_UIQMs(inp_dir)
print ("Input UIQMs >> Mean: {0} std: {1}".format(np.mean(inp_uqims), np.std(inp_uqims)))

## UIQMs of the enhanceded output images
#gen_dir = "eval_data/euvp_test/funie-gan/" 
gen_dir = "eval_data/ufo_test/deep-sesr/" 
gen_uqims = measure_UIQMs(gen_dir)
print ("Enhanced UIQMs >> Mean: {0} std: {1}".format(np.mean(gen_uqims), np.std(gen_uqims)))
```

And

```
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math

def mu_a(x, alpha_L=0.1, alpha_R=0.1):
    """
      Calculates the asymetric alpha-trimmed mean
    """
    # sort pixels by intensity - for clipping
    x = sorted(x)
    # get number of pixels
    K = len(x)
    # calculate T alpha L and T alpha R
    T_a_L = math.ceil(alpha_L*K)
    T_a_R = math.floor(alpha_R*K)
    # calculate mu_alpha weight
    weight = (1/(K-T_a_L-T_a_R))
    # loop through flattened image starting at T_a_L+1 and ending at K-T_a_R
    s   = int(T_a_L+1)
    e   = int(K-T_a_R)
    val = sum(x[s:e])
    val = weight*val
    return val

def s_a(x, mu):
    val = 0
    for pixel in x:
        val += math.pow((pixel-mu), 2)
    return val/len(x)

def _uicm(x):
    R = x[:,:,0].flatten()
    G = x[:,:,1].flatten()
    B = x[:,:,2].flatten()
    RG = R-G
    YB = ((R+G)/2)-B
    mu_a_RG = mu_a(RG)
    mu_a_YB = mu_a(YB)
    s_a_RG = s_a(RG, mu_a_RG)
    s_a_YB = s_a(YB, mu_a_YB)
    l = math.sqrt( (math.pow(mu_a_RG,2)+math.pow(mu_a_YB,2)) )
    r = math.sqrt(s_a_RG+s_a_YB)
    return (-0.0268*l)+(0.1586*r)

def sobel(x):
    dx = ndimage.sobel(x,0)
    dy = ndimage.sobel(x,1)
    mag = np.hypot(dx, dy)
    mag *= 255.0 / np.max(mag) 
    return mag

def eme(x, window_size):
    """
      Enhancement measure estimation
      x.shape[0] = height
      x.shape[1] = width
    """
    # if 4 blocks, then 2x2...etc.
    k1 = x.shape[1]/window_size
    k2 = x.shape[0]/window_size
    # weight
    w = 2./(k1*k2)
    blocksize_x = window_size
    blocksize_y = window_size
    # make sure image is divisible by window_size - doesn't matter if we cut out some pixels
    x = x[:blocksize_y*k2, :blocksize_x*k1]
    val = 0
    for l in range(k1):
        for k in range(k2):
            block = x[k*window_size:window_size*(k+1), l*window_size:window_size*(l+1)]
            max_ = np.max(block)
            min_ = np.min(block)
            # bound checks, can't do log(0)
            if min_ == 0.0: val += 0
            elif max_ == 0.0: val += 0
            else: val += math.log(max_/min_)
    return w*val

def _uism(x):
    """
      Underwater Image Sharpness Measure
    """
    # get image channels
    R = x[:,:,0]
    G = x[:,:,1]
    B = x[:,:,2]
    # first apply Sobel edge detector to each RGB component
    Rs = sobel(R)
    Gs = sobel(G)
    Bs = sobel(B)
    # multiply the edges detected for each channel by the channel itself
    R_edge_map = np.multiply(Rs, R)
    G_edge_map = np.multiply(Gs, G)
    B_edge_map = np.multiply(Bs, B)
    # get eme for each channel
    r_eme = eme(R_edge_map, 10)
    g_eme = eme(G_edge_map, 10)
    b_eme = eme(B_edge_map, 10)
    # coefficients
    lambda_r = 0.299
    lambda_g = 0.587
    lambda_b = 0.144
    return (lambda_r*r_eme) + (lambda_g*g_eme) + (lambda_b*b_eme)

def plip_g(x,mu=1026.0):
    return mu-x

def plip_theta(g1, g2, k):
    g1 = plip_g(g1)
    g2 = plip_g(g2)
    return k*((g1-g2)/(k-g2))

def plip_cross(g1, g2, gamma):
    g1 = plip_g(g1)
    g2 = plip_g(g2)
    return g1+g2-((g1*g2)/(gamma))

def plip_diag(c, g, gamma):
    g = plip_g(g)
    return gamma - (gamma * math.pow((1 - (g/gamma) ), c) )

def plip_multiplication(g1, g2):
    return plip_phiInverse(plip_phi(g1) * plip_phi(g2))
    #return plip_phiInverse(plip_phi(plip_g(g1)) * plip_phi(plip_g(g2)))

def plip_phiInverse(g):
    plip_lambda = 1026.0
    plip_beta   = 1.0
    return plip_lambda * (1 - math.pow(math.exp(-g / plip_lambda), 1 / plip_beta));

def plip_phi(g):
    plip_lambda = 1026.0
    plip_beta   = 1.0
    return -plip_lambda * math.pow(math.log(1 - g / plip_lambda), plip_beta)

def _uiconm(x, window_size):
    """
      Underwater image contrast measure
      https://github.com/tkrahn108/UIQM/blob/master/src/uiconm.cpp
      https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5609219
    """
    plip_lambda = 1026.0
    plip_gamma  = 1026.0
    plip_beta   = 1.0
    plip_mu     = 1026.0
    plip_k      = 1026.0
    # if 4 blocks, then 2x2...etc.
    k1 = x.shape[1]/window_size
    k2 = x.shape[0]/window_size
    # weight
    w = -1./(k1*k2)
    blocksize_x = window_size
    blocksize_y = window_size
    # make sure image is divisible by window_size - doesn't matter if we cut out some pixels
    x = x[:blocksize_y*k2, :blocksize_x*k1]
    # entropy scale - higher helps with randomness
    alpha = 1
    val = 0
    for l in range(k1):
        for k in range(k2):
            block = x[k*window_size:window_size*(k+1), l*window_size:window_size*(l+1), :]
            max_ = np.max(block)
            min_ = np.min(block)
            top = max_-min_
            bot = max_+min_
            if math.isnan(top) or math.isnan(bot) or bot == 0.0 or top == 0.0: val += 0.0
            else: val += alpha*math.pow((top/bot),alpha) * math.log(top/bot)
            #try: val += plip_multiplication((top/bot),math.log(top/bot))
    return w*val

def getUIQM(x):
    """
      Function to return UIQM to be called from other programs
      x: image
    """
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    ### UCIQE: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7300447
    #c1 = 0.4680; c2 = 0.2745; c3 = 0.2576
    ### UIQM https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7305804
    c1 = 0.0282; c2 = 0.2953; c3 = 3.5753
    uicm   = _uicm(x)
    uism   = _uism(x)
    uiconm = _uiconm(x, 10)
    uiqm = (c1*uicm) + (c2*uism) + (c3*uiconm)
    return uiqm
```

But after running the code an error message is getting generated continuously. saying:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/FUnIE-GAN/Evaluation/measure_uiqm.py", line 34, in <module>
    inp_uqims = measure_UIQMs(inp_dir)
  File "/content/FUnIE-GAN/Evaluation/measure_uiqm.py", line 22, in measure_UIQMs
    uiqm = getUIQM(np.array(im))
  File "/content/FUnIE-GAN/Evaluation/uqim_utils.py", line 187, in getUIQM
    uism   = _uism(x)
  File "/content/FUnIE-GAN/Evaluation/uqim_utils.py", line 101, in _uism
    r_eme = eme(R_edge_map, 10)
  File "/content/FUnIE-GAN/Evaluation/uqim_utils.py", line 71, in eme
    x = x[:blocksize_y*k2, :blocksize_x*k1]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi Team, After adding the changes as suggested another error for float is getting generated: <ipython-input-14-0ce121333167> in eme(x, window_size)
     72     x = x[:int(blocksize_y*k2), :int(blocksize_x*k1)]
     73     val = 0
---> 74     for l in range(k1):
     75         for k in range(k2):
     76             block = x[k*window_size:window_size*(k+1), l*window_size:window_size*(l+1)]

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `k1` and `k2` are floating point values, so when you make the `blocksize_y*k2` and `blocksize_x*k1` multiplications, the result are floats too. As Python doesn't support floats as indexes, you should make those values integers instead:

```python
x = x[:int(blocksize_y*k2), :int(blocksize_x*k1)]
```

Comment: Hi, After making the changes as suggested another error is generated saying "
  File "/content/FUnIE-GAN/Evaluation/uqim_utils.py", line 101, in _uism
    r_eme = eme(R_edge_map, 10)
  File "/content/FUnIE-GAN/Evaluation/uqim_utils.py", line 73, in eme
    for l in range(k1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".. Can you please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: The `range()` method does not support floats either, so you should also transform `k1` into an integer: `for l in range(int(k1))`

Comment: You can also try to directly create the `k1` and `k2` variables as integers by adding an extra slash in the division: `k1 = x.shape[1]//window_size`    `k2 = x.shape[0]//window_size`